# Importing cocoapod in example project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, appdelegate

I'm trying to test the cocoapod I am currently developing in the example project but I am having issues getting some objects in the cocoapod in the example project.

Here is the repository for the cocoapod https://github.com/vinnyoodles/DualSlideMenu

And the error I am getting is in the AppDelegate.swift
[image: AppDelegate.swift]

It does not give me errors when I am importing the cocoapod, but I cannot access the class that I am using.

I am not getting any errors when inheriting my view controller classes in the storyboard, however.
[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Could you add some of `DualSlideMenuViewController` declaration to the question ? It will make it easier to understand in the futur if the project happen to disappear from github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark `DualSlideMenuViewController` as `public` in the pod's code.

```
public class DualSlideMenuViewController {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even think about project scope :))